# Adding "oauth" values to my Zendesk app's manifest crashes my ZAT server

Tags: oauth, zendesk-app

I am completely new to building Zendesk apps so I have been working my way through the documentation:
https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/apps/build-an-app/build-your-first-support-app/part-1-laying-the-groundwork/

My client side app runs inside the Zendesk ticket sidebar. It needs to pull data from an external api, so I am adding these values into the manifest.json (as outline in the docs):

```
  "oauth": {
    "client_id": "...",
    "client_secret": "...",
    "authorize_uri": "...",
    "access_token_uri": "...",
    "scope": "read write"
  },
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "access_token",
      "type": "oauth"
    }
  ]
```

However as soon as I add the `oauth` keys into the manifest, my local ZAT server  crashes. So the server will startup correctly, but as soon as I refresh Zendesk in my browser the server will crash. The resulting Ruby crash report doesn't give much away (to me at least).

So I'm pretty much falling at the first hurdle here. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I will just mention that I'm on an M1 MacBook, just in case there are any incompatibilities with ZAT Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure the reason my ZAT server kept crashing, but the solution was to abandon it in favour of the new ZCLI server:

https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050791614-Introducing-ZCLI-The-Zendesk-Command-Line-Interface-Beta